# Xcode: Swift framework not generating header update

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, frameworks

I'm trying to implement a framework using swift but the header file is not been updated with the class or the functions:

Here is my code in my swift file:

```
public class one{
    public func two(name:String) -> String {
        print(name)
    }
}
@objc public class SwiftInObjc:NSObject {
    public func bla(){
    }
}
```

After I build this is what I see in my header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char sampleFramework[];
framework using statements like #import <sampleFramework/PublicHeader.h>
```

How can generate update to the header file?